# build histograms of the distribution of all numerical variables

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I need to build histograms of the distribution of all numerical variables and i really dont catch how to properly do this

```
import pandas as pd
ind = [5375, 11681, 5325, 679, 12625, 8090, 11518, 16341, 2607,1742]
dats = {
'index' : [5376, 11682, 5326, 680, 12626, 8091, 11519, 16342, 2608,1743],
'date': [2011-8-16, 2012-5-6,2011-8-14,2011-1-31,2012-6-15,2011-12-8, 2011-4-30,2012-11-18, 2011-4-23,2011-3-18],
'season': [4,3,4,2,3,1,3,1,3,2],
'yr': [0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0],
'mnth': [8,5,8,1,6,12,4,11,4,3],
'hr': [21,22,19,15,6,18,3,15,13,7],
'holiday': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
'weekday': [2,0,0,1,5,4,1,0,6,5],
'workingday': [1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1],
'weathersit': [1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1],
'temp':[0.72,0.56,0.72,0.16,0.54,0.28,0.40,0.42,0.52,0.4],
'atemp': [0.6667, 0.5303, 0.6970, 0.1818, 0.5152, 0.2727, 0.4091, 0.4242, 0.5000, 0.4091],
'hum':[0.54, 0.73, 0.74, 0.59, 0.83, 0.52, 0.76, 0.54, 0.83, 0.66],
'windspeed': [0.0000, 0.1642, 0.2239, 0.1343, 0.1343, 0.2239, 0.1642, 0.2836, 0.3881, 0.1940],
'cnt': [215, 157, 259, 44, 151, 318, 4, 407, 312, 123]
}
data = pd.DataFrame(data=dats, index=ind)
```

As i understand, numerical variables are each of these columns

```
data_numerical = data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(20, 10)) #necessary line
plt.bar(data=data_numerical, x=variable, ax=subplot)
```

So what do i need to fix here?

Comment: Date is not numerical. You need *multiple* *histograms*, not *one* *bar chart*. Pandas itself has a method for that: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html

Comment: If you can solve your problem, please post the answer!

Comment: fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(20, 10))
data_numerical.hist() something is wrong here

Answer (score 0):

First of all, not all of these columns are numerical. `'date'` clearly isn't. Since your "necessary line" only produces four plots, I assume only the weather variables are meant:

```
columns = ['temp', 'atemp', 'hum', 'windspeed']
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(20, 10)) #necessary line
```

For making the histograms themselves, pandas has a [dedicated method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html). The only tricky part is accessing each Axes object in the 2x2 matrix given by the `axs` variable:

```
axs
Out[3]: 
array([[<AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:>],
       [<AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:>]], dtype=object)
```

but you can use `.flatten()` for that. Now just iterate over the columns and Axes objects, combining them with `zip`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dats)
for ax, col in zip(axs.flatten(), columns):
    df.hist(column=col, ax=ax)
```

The result:
[image]

If you don't really need your "necessary line" verbatim like that, there's an easier way to achieve the same result:

```
columns = ['temp', 'atemp', 'hum', 'windspeed']
df = pd.DataFrame(dats)
df[columns].hist()
```